# Why is my drupal menu not showing styled correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I am using the Bootstrap drupal theme. My menu items show up vertically, with styling (underline on hover and a dot next to the them. Am I missing something in my PHP or in my CSS? Also my hover dropdown isn't working. Not sure if that has to do with the way it is showing up now.

```
<div class="menu_wrapper">

  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="#">

                <?php $navigation = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
                                    print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $navigation));?>

                            </a>
                    </li>

          </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

  </nav><!-- end main-menu -->

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Menu */

.menu-wrapper {
    background-color: #c32523;
    opacity: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.navbar {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The menu wrapper class in your HTML is `menu_wrapper` with an underscore but in your css you used a hyphen `.menu-wrapper`. Change 1 of them accordingly and your styles will apply.